# WordPress action when main page/post is loaded

Tags: wordpress

The the_post action is called whenever a post is displayed. What action is the best to use when the main page/post loads?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific action for the main page but depending on your needs you can hook `the_post` and call the function [`is_home`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) or `is_front_page` to determine if the main page is currently being viewed.

Available actions are listed [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).  Depending on what you want to do with the main page and when, you can hook `the_post`, or possible `wp`, `wp_head`, `get_header` to run the check for the main page and run your code if that condition is met.

Comment: add_action('wp_head', 'wp_do_things_in_frontend', 99);
function wp_do_things_in_frontend()
{...}